# Powershell: Forcing evaluation of a block of code in Add-member's -value option

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to import users into an active directory using a CSV file and a powershell script. I create a CSV with the headers normally associated with an AD object:

`mail,name,givenName,middleName,surname,company,department,title,plaintextPassword,path,description,userPrincipalName`

...and filled it up.

Now I want to use Powershell's `new-aduser` cmmdlet to generate users for each item in this sheet - the problem I'm having is that `new-aduser` requires a `SecureString`, not just a normal string for an account's password. Skipping this conversion results in my users being created correctly, but with no passwords and their account disabled.

The command I'm using is as follows:

```
import-csv .\users.csv | add-member -passthru -memberType NoteProperty -value {$_ | select plaintextPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -fromplaintext -force}
```

The result is user records like the following:

```
mail              : tom.fubar@contoso.com
name              : tom.fubar
givenName         : Tom
middleName        :
surname           : Fubar
company           : Contoso
department        : IT
title             : Technician
accountPassword   : LongPasswordThatFitsADComplexityRequirements123!
path              : OU=UserAccounts,OU=IT,OU=employees,DC=contoso,DC=com
description       : 
userPrincipalName : tom.fubar@contoso.com
encodedPassword   : {$_ | select accountPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asplaintext -force}
```

The bit of code that should be evaluated for converting the plaintext password to a SecureString is being passed verbatim, rather than executed inline.

What is the proper way to force the code block to be evaluated, and use its result as the argument to `New-Member -value`?

#### Tried:

- Enclosing the script block in `$(...)` - **Results in a null NoteProperty added to the object**
- Replacing the `{...}` with `$(...)` - **Results in a null NoteProperty added to the object**

(as shown by piping the whole command to `Get-Member`)

Comment: Are you looking for a `ScriptProperty` or just evaluate at assignment?

Comment: I think it just needs to be evaluated, since all the other output that goes into `New-Aduser` is of the `NoteProperty` type @Eris

Comment: Use `-Value $(...)` instead of `-Value {..}` ?

Comment: That results in a null property being added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution I've found is to not bother with Add-Member, instead use a calculated property like so:

```
import-csv .\users.csv | 
    select -Property *, @{
        n="encodedPassword"; 
        e={$_.plaintestPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -fromplaintext -force}}
```

(Removed broken add-member after comment from @PetSerAl)

Comment: *# Uses $( ... ) to "force" immediate evaluation* Script block literal still evaluated to script block object, but not to result of script block invocation.

Comment: And that's why I dislike `add-member` in powershell 3+

Comment: This answer worked perfectly. Turns out, I was already running the right version of Powershell. Looks like you're SOL if you run an old version though - `add-member` doesn't appear to work no matter how you phrase the command.

Answer (score 6):

[Eris has posted a perfectly valid workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834743/3905079), but to answer why it won't work for you, it's because `$_` doesn't apply to any old script block. It's "special" and used only in certain contexts.

Additionally, `-NotePropertyValue` expects a static value.

Instead, you could add a `ScriptProperty` like so:

```
import-csv .\users.csv | 
    add-member -passthru -memberType ScriptProperty -value {$this.plaintextPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -fromplaintext -force}
```

In this context for example, `$_` is not even used; you have to use `$this` to refer to the parent object.

This does result in the script being processed every time the property is accessed though. If you don't want that, and want to do a static value assignment that's calculated per object, then you must enumerate yourself:

```
import-csv .\users.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $val = $_ | select plaintextPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -fromplaintext -force
    $_ | add-member -passthru -memberType NoteProperty -value $val -Force
}
```

Comment: I already did the thing I was writing this bit of code for, but won't that cause issues when you pass something a `ScriptProperty` when it wants a `NoteProperty`, or am I misunderstanding how the type system works?

Comment: @MikeyT.K. I think you might be misunderstanding it. The code reading the property generally doesn't know or care what type of property it is. It gets accessed with dot `.` notation or `select` or whatever, but code must be written specifically to determine the property type, so it's unlikely that it would matter. What is sometimes important is whether the scriptblock that generates the value is "expensive" or time consuming, or has side effects.

Comment: One useful advantage of the ScriptProperty used here is that if you update the property behind (.plaintextPassword) the value you have in the ScriptProperty is always going to be contextually right.

Comment: Yes absolutely, what @ChrisDent said! It makes it into a "live" property, for better or worse. You have to determine whether that's a desirable trait or not for your specific situation (in this case, it probably is).